# Why don't these static functions return as expected from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, static

I'm trying to use multiple threads to make one function run concurrently with another, but when the function that the new thread is running uses a static function, it always returns 0 for some reason.

I'm using Boost for the threading, on Linux, and the static functions work exactly as expected when not using threads. I'm pretty sure this isn't a data race issue because if I join the thread directly after making it (not giving any other code a chance to change anything), the problem persists.

The function that the thread is created in:

```
void WorldIOManager::createWorld(unsigned int seed, std::string worldName, bool isFlat) {
    boost::thread t( [=]() { P_createWorld(seed, worldName, isFlat); } );
    t.join();
    //P_createWorld(seed, worldName, isFlat); // This works perfectly fine
}
```

The part of P_createWorld that uses a static function (The function that the newly-created thread actually runs):
`m_world->chunks[i]->tiles[y][x] = createBlock(chunkData[i].tiles[y][x].id, chunkData[i].tiles[y][x].pos, m_world->chunks[i]);`

m_world is a struct that contains an array of Chunks, which has a two dimensional array of Tiles, which each have texture IDs associated with a texture in a cache. createBlock returns a pointer to a new tile pointer, completely initialized. The static function in question belongs to a statically-linked library, and is defined as follows:

```
namespace GLEngine {
    //This is a way for us to access all our resources, such as
    //Models or textures.
    class ResourceManager
    {
    public:
        static GLTexture getTexture(std::string texturePath);

    private:
        static TextureCache _textureCache;
    };
}
```

Also, its implementation:

```
#include "ResourceManager.h"
namespace GLEngine {
    TextureCache ResourceManager::_textureCache;

    GLTexture ResourceManager::getTexture(std::string texturePath) {
       return _textureCache.getTexture(texturePath);
    }
}
```

Expected result: For each tile to actually get assigned its proper texture ID

Actual result: Every tile, no matter the texturePath, is assigned 0 as its texture ID.

If you need any more code like the constructor for a tile or createBlock(), I'll happily add it, I just don't really know what information is relevant in this kind of situation...

So, as I stated before, all of this works perfectly if I don't have a thread, so my final question is: Is there some sort of undefined behaviour that has to do with static functions being called by threads, or am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does the compiler emit any warnings or errors?

Comment: No, it compiles the exact same as if I weren't using threads

Comment: So how "clever" is your texture cache? Does it need to worry about scenarios like one thread is forcing the load of a texture while another thread is reading another texture. Perhaps 2 threads are both loading the same texture - which one actually lands in the cache - what happens to the other one? You may need some mutexes to stop non-determinate interactions here? stl containers are not intrinsically thread-safe when written to.

Comment: So, as of right now, the only multithreading done in the program is where I have the issue, and as joining the thread directly after creation doesn't prevent the issue, I don't think the issue is caused by 2 threads loading textures at the same time

Comment: What is P_createWorld ? Where is m_world defined? When you say that every tile is zero, you mean that you put a print statement or a breakpoint and you actually observed that the output of createBlock is 0 or you infer it from inspecting m_world? What I am trying to say is that the thread might be populating another m_world, that would be the case if m_world was thread_local for example. Most likely I am wrong, but I am trying to give another perspective.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts P_createWorld structures a world's tiles, and populates the member m_world, which is stored as a private pointer with the only getter also returning the pointer, so I don't think that there is a chance another m_world is being populated. Also, I used some breakpoints in gdb before and after the textureId was assigned (using the static function GetTexture) in the Tile constructor to find out that it was always simply staying as 0. I don't think that m_world is thread local because 'this' was passed in the lambda used to create the thread

Comment: OpenGL contexts have thread affinity.  I wonder if you're trying to make GL calls on the background thread?  If so, you will need some extra machinery, like a 2nd GL context, explicit state sharing between the 2, and carefully restricting which types of operations occur in the bg.
See https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading
or search online for "opengl shared context".

Comment: @fifoforlifo Ah, I just looked wayyyy deep into my texture loading functions and it seems there were some GL calls there. Let me see if this was the problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @fifoforlifo mentioned, OpenGL contexts have thread affinity, and it turns out I was making GL calls deeper into my texture loading function. I created a second GL context and turned on context sharing and then it began to work. Thanks a lot, @fifoforlifo!